# how to stop running any script inside html?

Tags: html

I am creating a webpage with 2 fields (username, password) using html, i want to know how to stop someone from bypassing without entering username and password by running any script inside those field  ?

Answer (score 5):

You can't stop the user from running script, nor can you guarantee that they will run your script.  The browser, and any scripts that run there, are outside of your control.

Any important security code needs to run on the server - that's where you need to validate the fields.  That's the piece of the system that you control.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to offer two way security, i recommend todo everything on server-side like @RichieHindle suggests but also running Javascript code client side to prevent unnecessary communication to the server side is also good practice.

Comment: so is there any way to prevent running Javascript code on client side ?

Comment: @user2549572: Besides taking the site offline?  No.  Browsers go through some effort to ensure that you can't impose restrictions like that.  Once i have your HTML and JS, my browser will let me do basically whatever i please with them...including running any scripts i want to, or disabling the code that does the validation, etc.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is for you to run a javascript validation script for your fields.. Has in the script would verify that 'said' fields have data if not they prevent a validation to the server side. Hence my position on 2 way validation (Client and Server side).